# laravel where if get a single value

Tags: laravel

[image]

Hello there
I want to write a query. I want to select the `meter` field with `status=1`, but if there is no `status=1`, The last field with `status=0` will be selected.

Comment: We're not a code writing service, please add any relevant code showing us what you have tried and where you're stuck. If you're unsure what to include, have a read of [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Order the results by `status`, then take the first row.

Comment: please describe more because I didn't get your question there is no status id in your table it's only status or else id so describe properly @onur

Answer (score 0):

```
//get latest row with status = 1
    $unitMeter = DB::table('unit_meters')->where('status','=',1)->latest()->first();
    if (!$unitMeter){// if is null
        $unitMeter = DB::table('unit_meters')->where('status','=',0)->latest()->first();
    }
    if ($unitMeter){// if isn't null ( mean it's object )
        $meter = $unitMeter->meter;
    }
```

Also, add this in top of your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: There's no need to write two DB queries here. You should use `->orderBy('status')->first()` (and make sure that the `status` column is sorted correctly to return the desired row first. Ceejayoz mentions this in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73803312/laravel-where-if-get-a-single-value#comment130319559_73803312).